Python - errors when calling cv2.ml.TrainData_create(): - responses data type = 19 is not supported - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'responses'
I am following the following tutorial:
https://www.opencvhelp.org/tutorials/deep-learning/training-models/
Following the instructions using the Caltech-101 dataset, I preprocessed the images (converted them to 128x128 grayscale, 8-bit .jpg images) and separated them into train and test datasets.
The train dataset is in the './train_dataset' directory with a hierarchy:
./train_dataset
|
|--accordion
|  |--image_0001.jpg
|  ...
|  |--image_0055.jpg
|
|--airplanes
|  |--image_0001.jpg
|  ...
|  |--image_0800.jpg
|
...
|--yin_yang
   |--image_0001.jpg
   ...
   |--image_0060.jpg

Minimum reproducible example
When I try to create a TrainData object using:
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob
import os

image_folder = './train_dataset'

hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor((128,128), (16,16), (8,8), (8,8), 9)
train_features = []
train_labels = []

for category_folder in glob.glob(os.path.join(image_folder, '*')):
    category = os.path.basename(category_folder)
    for image_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(category_folder, '*.jpg')):
        image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        feature = hog.compute(image)
        train_features.append(feature)
        train_labels.append(category)

train_features = np.array(train_features).squeeze()
train_labels = np.array(train_labels)

train_data = cv2.ml.TrainData_create(train_features, cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, train_labels)

I get the following error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
---->      train_data = cv2.ml.TrainData_create(train_features, cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, train_labels)


error: OpenCV(4.5.4) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'TrainData_create'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - responses data type = 19 is not supported
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'responses'

Troubleshooting Attempt
Printing train_features and train_labels using:
print(train_features)
print(train_labels)

I get:
[[0.         0.         0.         ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.01044914 0.01131945 0.00497587 ... 0.31986603 0.34548187 0.29508054]
 [0.         0.         0.         ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
 ...
 [0.06217989 0.01798008 0.04473049 ... 0.04874689 0.0164769  0.13794596]
 [0.16842279 0.1584084  0.14274834 ... 0.11159177 0.07674719 0.10536178]
 [0.26677153 0.04394426 0.02935512 ... 0.01491783 0.01274435 0.19201462]]

['yin_yang' 'yin_yang' 'yin_yang' ... 'dollar_bill' 'dollar_bill'
 'dollar_bill']

And checking their type and shape using:
print(type(train_features))
print(type(train_labels))
print(train_features.shape)
print(train_labels.shape)

I get:
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(7356, 8100)
(7356, )

If I understand it correctly, the 'responses' argument is the position in which I input train_labels, which is a numpy.ndarray containing string elements.  The error suggests that 'responses' should be cv::UMat.  After searching the internet, it seems that cv2.UMat() is equivalent to a np.float32() datatype.
Does this mean the cv2.ml.TrainData_create() function does not accept strings as category labels but only numbers?  Or does it have to be handled differently?
If I try to convert train_labels to cv2.UMat like so:
train_data = cv2.ml.TrainData_create(train_features, cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, cv2.UMat(train_labels))

I get the following error message:
error: OpenCV(4.10.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'UMat'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Argument 'usageFlags' is required to be an integer
>  - UMat() missing required argument 'cols' (pos 2)
>  - UMat() missing required argument 'type' (pos 2)
>  - UMat() missing required argument 'cols' (pos 2)
>  - UMat() missing required argument 'type' (pos 2)
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'm'
>  - UMat() missing required argument 'rowRange' (pos 2)
>  - UMat() missing required argument 'roi' (pos 2)
>  - UMat() missing required argument 'ranges' (pos 2)

So I can't just force the conversion.

It doesn't like it being a bunch of strings (the documentation of the constructor seems quite explicit about that). Forget about the UMat part, it's just trying various overloads. Just randomly casting things to UMat if you don't understand its purpose won't solve anything.

[mre] required. we have to guess here.

It looks like I will have to convert train_labels to an array of integers then and give that a try.

Convert the array of strings, train_labels, to an array of integers:
import numpy as np

labels_unique = np.unique(train_labels)
train_labels_int = train_labels.copy()

i=0
for unique_label in labels_unique:
    print(str(i)+': '+unique_label)
    train_labels_int[train_labels == unique_label] = i
    i += 1

train_labels_int = train_labels_int.astype(np.int32)

This prints:
0: BACKGROUND_Google
1: Faces
2: Faces_easy
3: Leopards
4: Motorbikes
5: accordion
6: airplanes
7: anchor
8: ant
9: barrel
10: bass
11: beaver
12: binocular
13: bonsai
14: brain
15: brontosaurus
16: buddha
17: butterfly
18: camera
19: cannon
20: car_side
21: ceiling_fan
22: cellphone
23: chair
24: chandelier
25: cougar_body
26: cougar_face
27: crab
28: crayfish
29: crocodile
30: crocodile_head
31: cup
32: dalmatian
33: dollar_bill
34: dolphin
35: dragonfly
36: electric_guitar
37: elephant
38: emu
39: euphonium
40: ewer
41: ferry
42: flamingo
43: flamingo_head
44: garfield
45: gerenuk
46: gramophone
47: grand_piano
48: hawksbill
49: headphone
50: hedgehog
51: helicopter
52: ibis
53: inline_skate
54: joshua_tree
55: kangaroo
56: ketch
57: lamp
58: laptop
59: llama
60: lobster
61: lotus
62: mandolin
63: mayfly
64: menorah
65: metronome
66: minaret
67: nautilus
68: octopus
69: okapi
70: pagoda
71: panda
72: pigeon
73: pizza
74: platypus
75: pyramid
76: revolver
77: rhino
78: rooster
79: saxophone
80: schooner
81: scissors
82: scorpion
83: sea_horse
84: snoopy
85: soccer_ball
86: stapler
87: starfish
88: stegosaurus
89: stop_sign
90: strawberry
91: sunflower
92: tick
93: trilobite
94: umbrella
95: watch
96: water_lilly
97: wheelchair
98: wild_cat
99: windsor_chair
100: wrench
101: yin_yang

Now using .TrainData_create has no issues if train_labels_int is passed instead of train_labels:
train_data = cv2.ml.TrainData_create(train_features, cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, train_labels_int)

To convert an integer label back to the string label, use:
labels_unique[integer_label]

So for example labels_unique[0] is 'BACKGROUND_Google', labels_unique[1] is 'Faces', etc.
An array of integer labels can also be converted to an array of corresponding string labels, for example, labels_unique[[0,1]] is ['BACKGROUND_Google','Faces'].
